# Input Form connecting directly to Excel Spreadsheet using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

We're thinking of creating an input form using apps script that would feed its values directly into an excel spreadsheet. Is it possible, or it only applies to Google sheet? I would love to hear your thoughts about this.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the Excel file cannot be directly modified using Google Apps Script. If you want to put a value to the Excel file, as one of several workarounds, how about this flow? 1. Convert the Excel file to Google Spreadsheet. 2. Put a value to the converted Google Spreadsheet. 3. Convert Google Spreadsheet to Excel file. 4. Overwrite the original Excel file by the converted Excel file. By this flow. a value is put to the Excel file without changing the file ID. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike for the quick response and for the suggestion. I think the better option here would be to directly update it to a SQL Server database. What do you think?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you can use it, I think that the process cost might be lower than that of my proposal. But I cannot explain quantitatively because I cannot confirm this. I apologize for this.

Comment: Sure @Tanaike. As always, thank for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there is no way to write to Excel from Apps Script.

As sugested by [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) on the comments, you can:

## 1 Upload/Convert/Edit/Download

You can [upload your excel file and convert it to a Google sheets](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types_) file.
Then, [insert your data from Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).
Finally, [download the Excel file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) from Google Drive.

## 2 Use a Database

You can also use Apps Script to insert the data into a database that Excel can query.
This *might* be more expensive than the first solution, if you don't already have a Database for this.

Comment: Hi ZertorH, thank you for your response also. I'll share this to our team today and get their thoughts also.